# How to use admitad api for client authorization?

Tags: api, curl, authorization, affiliate

https://developers.admitad.com/en/doc/api_en/auth/auth-client/
is the link to documentation.

[image: Admited client authorization]

how to use this curl -H for api integration.

Comment: Are you answering the question in your title? To do that please write a more elaborate question and then create an answering post below. Then answering your own question is appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.